# What is the right way to initialize a struct within another struct?

Tags: struct, initialization, rust

What is the right way to do something like this?

```
struct Child {
    field: i32,
}

struct Parent {
    child: Child,
}

...

let parent: Parent = Parent {
    child { field: 0 },
};
```

This does work, but is more verbose than I'd like:

```
let child: Child = Child {
    field: 0,
};

let parent: Parent = Parent {
    child: child,
};
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to state the type of the variable twice. `var_name: Type = Type {..}` can just be `var_name = Type {...}`. Type inference is your friend; this isn't Ye Olde C(++) or Ye Olde Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just embed the literal:

```
Parent {
    child: Child {
        field: 0,
    },
};
```